# How to add Action Listener from another class java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I want to develop a very basic application, well here is the code, I have 4 classes one is the main class, the second one is `JMenuBar`, the third one is `Panel` and the fourth one is for Action Listener. at the moment my problem is here how to add instance of Action Listener for class of `JMenuBar`, till i could do some action.

---

```
public class My_Action implements ActionListener {


    public My_Action() {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    }

}
```

---

```
public class My_Menu extends JMenuBar {


    private My_Action my_action = new My_Action();
    JMenu file;
    JMenu Edit;
    JMenu help;

    public My_Menu() {
        file = new JMenu("File");
        Edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        help = new JMenu("help");


        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("file");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Setting");
        JMenuItem item4 = new JMenuItem("Color");
        JMenuItem item5 = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem item6 = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        file.add(item1);
        file.add(item2);
        file.add(item3);
        file.add(item4);
        file.add(item5);
        file.add(item6);

        file.addSeparator();
        this.add(file);
        this.add(Edit);
        this.add(help);
        item1.addActionListener(my_action);


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){
          System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Are you getting any errors while you are compiling/running your code?

Comment: first of all thanks for quick respond, i have no error just i want to implement the Action Listener from  My_Action to the My_Menu class , how can i do it?

Comment: The thing here is, you are taking a wrong approach. `JMenuBar` can have multiple `JMenu` items and each `JMenu` can have multiple `JMenuItem`. An `ActionListener` should be added on `JMenuItem` and not on `JMenuBar`

Comment: If you want to use only one `ActionListener` for all of `JMenuItem`s you may want to use different **ActionCommand**s for them. Then you in your `actionPerformed` method you should use a control structure such as `if-else` or `switch-case` to find out which of them is clicked.

Comment: if you could brother me too added  in,   item1.addActionListener(my_action); not in JMenu

Answer (score 0):

This is my test program for you.

Check the console output when executing the menu program.

```
package just.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class My_Menu extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private My_Action my_action = new My_Action();

    JMenu file;
    JMenu Edit;
    JMenu help;

    public My_Menu() {
        file = new JMenu("File");
        Edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        help = new JMenu("help");

        this.add(file);
        this.add(Edit);
        this.add(help);

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("file");
        item1.setActionCommand("file");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("New");
        item2.setActionCommand("New");
        JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Setting");
        item3.setActionCommand("Setting");
        JMenuItem item4 = new JMenuItem("Color");
        item4.setActionCommand("Color");
        JMenuItem item5 = new JMenuItem("Print");
        item5.setActionCommand("Print");
        JMenuItem item6 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        item6.setActionCommand("Exit");

        JMenuItem item7 = new JMenuItem("edit1");
        item7.setActionCommand("edit1");
        JMenuItem item8 = new JMenuItem("edit2");
        item8.setActionCommand("edit2");
        JMenuItem item9 = new JMenuItem("about..");
        item9.setActionCommand("about");


        file.add(item1);
        file.add(item2);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(item3);
        file.add(item4);
        file.add(item5);
        file.add(item6);


        Edit.add(item7);
        Edit.add(item8);


        help.add(item9);

        item1.addActionListener(my_action);
        item2.addActionListener(my_action);
        item3.addActionListener(my_action);
        item4.addActionListener(my_action);
        item5.addActionListener(my_action);

        item7.addActionListener(this);
        item8.addActionListener(this);
        item9.addActionListener(this);

        file.addActionListener(this);
        Edit.addActionListener(this);
        help.addActionListener(my_action);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println("----1----\n" + command);

        //System.exit(0);
    }

    class My_Action implements ActionListener {

        public My_Action() {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println("----2----\n" + command);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();

                JPanel jp = new JPanel();
                jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                f.add(new My_Menu(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                jp.setSize(500,400);
                f.setSize(800, 600);
                f.setVisible(true);

                //f.pack();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

You can just add a addActionListener to the component in which you have to send a message.

```
item1.addActionListener(my_action);
```

or

```
item7.addActionListener(this);
```

Don't forget to implement a ActionListener on your My_Menu class.

Comment: The Event-Handling could be improved when you add an [`ActionCommand`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand(java.lang.String) "setActionCommand") to the `JMenuItem`s and later read them in the ActionListener with [`ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand())

Comment: i did this one also but it does not do any action

Comment: i went in my_action class and put System.out.print("Hello"); is working now but i dont know why my action is not working in class my_jmenu

Comment: Have you tried my test code in your dev environment? I've just updated my test code with action commands for you. I think you have to show me all codes.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is right.
It should call action performed when you click on file menu item. Just put a print ln in that method to see it being called.

Comment: This is best suited as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: thanks for your quick respond, okay how can i implement the action listener to the item2

Comment: i went in my_action class and put System.out.print("Hello"); is working now but i dont know why my action is not working in class my_jmenu –

Comment: also i implement action listener in class my_jmenu